# Calling Python Function from JavaScript in PyQt5 Application - Uncaught ReferenceError: qt is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

I am working on a PyQt5 application that uses `QWebEngineView`, and I want to call a Python function from JavaScript. I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416790/pyqt-qtwebchannel-calling-python-function-from-javascript), and I've implemented the code as follows:

main.py

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, pyqtSlot 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel

HTML_PATH = join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), 'page.html')

class WebEngineView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def foo(self):
        print('bar')



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.browser = WebEngineView()
        self.channel = QWebChannel()
        self.channel.registerObject('backend', self.browser)
        self.browser.page().setWebChannel(self.channel)

        self.browser.setPage(WebEnginePage(self.browser))
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(HTML_PATH)
        self.browser.load(url)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        

class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, message, lineNumber, sourceID):
        print(f"[JS Message] Line-{lineNumber}:",message)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PyQt5 and QWebEngineView Example</h1>
    <button onclick="callPython()">Call Python</button>
    <script>
        function callPython(){
            backend.foo();
        }
        var backend;
        new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
            backend = channel.objects.backend;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I am encountering the following error in my browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: qt is not defined
```

Python version 3.8.0, PyQt5==5.15.10, PyQtWebEngine==5.15.6

Comment: You're setting a new QWebEnginePage, but you set the channel on the previous one. Move `self.browser.setPage()` *before* `self.browser.page().setWebChannel(self.channel)`.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you. That fixed the error. Now I'm getting `Property 'X'' of object 'WebEngineView' has no notify signal and is not constant, value updates in HTML will be broken! ` warnings. What causes it?

Comment: See this post: [Warnings when instantiating QWebChannel object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58906917). Either install a dummy message handler (`QtCore.qInstallMessageHandler(lambda *args: None)`) or use a separate backend (subclassing QObject) and eventually implement proper signals to communicate with the view.